# ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException springboot weblogic

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a Springboot application to weblogic. I am seeing the following error in the log.

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1035)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:996)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:617)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:547)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:71)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3311)
at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3341)
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:232)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumValue(AnnotationParser.java:483)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:347)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:132)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.AnnotationAncestry.isExtendedAnnotationDeep(AnnotationAncestry.java:107)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.AnnotationAncestry.isExtendedAnnotation(AnnotationAncestry.java:93)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.getAnnotationsOfInterest(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:882)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.access$600(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:850)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:666)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.hasAnnotatedClasses(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:715)
at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.hasCDIEnablingAnnotations(CDIUtils.java:835)
at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isWebModuleCDIEnabled(CDIUtils.java:411)
at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isModuleCdiEnabled(CDIUtils.java:661)
at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtensionFactory.create(CDIModuleExtensionFactory.java:39)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionAppInternal(AppTransition.java:32)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:138)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:678)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:54)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:211)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:677)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)


weblogic.application.ModuleException: Module null can not be activated, not in ACTIVATED state: NEW
  at weblogic.diagnostics.module.WLDFModule.activate(WLDFModule.java:334)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:57)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:114)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    ...
```

From the stack trace, I can't see any application specific classes.
POM.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-api</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>app description</description>
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
        <spring.version>2.4.1</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any idea?

Comment: That class comes from data... are you sure you don't need it in your pom.xml?

Comment: No, I don't have any database related operations for this application

Comment: Is this the **full stacktrace** or is there more to it? Looks like it got cut off (and I expect the actual culprit to be in there). Also as you are running on Weblogic make sure you have set precedence for classes from the war instead of the server (as weblogic ships internally with a Spring version as well).

Comment: full stack trace added.

Comment: Can you please add your pom.xml and application.yml to the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Class : org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException is defined in Spring-DAO.Please can you Check do you have the dependency.
like spring-dao

Comment: No, I don't have any database related operations for this application. I don't need any any of data access related dependancies

Comment: Can you check once @ComponentScan and package.

Comment: (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)